# Set font-size of a <div>-box to h2

Tags: css, eclipse, html

I get a warning in Eclipse: *Invalid location of tag `<div>`*

```
<h2>
    <div wicket:id="errorPage.infoheader"></div>
</h2>
```

I want to get rid of it. So, I have to set the size of a div-box to h2 **inside** because than, the warning will be gone.

Can I add the `<h2>`-tag in the div box? Something like this: `<div wicket:id="errorPage.infoheader" h2></div>` or add a class to a `css`-file to set the font of my div-box to "h2"?

I've searched on many websites, but the only thing that they show is, how to edit the h2-tag.

What I **don't** want to do, is simply add `<h2>`-tags around my `<div>`-box or edit my h2-tag:

`<h2><div wicket:id="errorPage.infoheader"></div></h2>`

Answer (score 2):

`H2` is a tag name, so it isn't possible this way.

In case you defined the `h2` style yourself in CSS, you can give the same style to the div, like this:

```
h2, #theDiv {
    h2 styles...
}
```

In your case, the warning is because a block element cannot be inside a heading.

Try to put the `<h2>` tag INSIDE the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one identifier per HTML element. Try using the tags inside the 'divs'

```
<div id="boxId">
<h2>Text with h2 styling </h2>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. On normal conditions, that should work well. But as you see, I'm using wicket and so there will be generated content in the div and this content isn't h2-style. I've tested it.

Answer (score 0):

A common option is to define a class that is the same as the heading tags.

Thus in your basic css you do

```
h1, .h1 {
your styles
}

h2, .h2 {
your styles
}
```

etc.

So you could do

```
<h1 class="h2"> Some Text </h1}
```

and it would still look like an `h2` but semantically it's an `h1`'

`<div class="h2> </div>` would then work.